# How do I find out (when running a program) how a struct is aligned?

Tags: rust, memory, memory-alignment

I have a struct `Data` that would be accessed frequently in an array, so it makes a siginificant improvement to align it with certain size.

Yet it's member variable can be configure to different type (either `f32` or `f64`) through a macro (`pub type Float = f32;` or `pub type Float = f64;`). I'm fine with recompiling the program when data type changed. The problem is: for these 2 types, I should align `Data` with different size (32 bytes or 64 bytes) if performance is a concern.

So how can I define a function to detect incorrect alignment to warn me when running this program?
e.g.

```rust
if type_name::<Float>() == "f64" && alignment(Data) == 32 {
    panic!("You should align Data with 64 bytes instead of 32 bytes");
}
```

or even, parameterize `32` from `#[repr(align(32))]` throug a marco or something?

---

full code:

```rust
pub type Float = f32;
//pub type Float = f64;

#[repr(align(32))]
struct Data {
    value: [Float; 6],
    offset: u32,
    num: u16,
    axis: u8,
}

fn main() {
    // data f32 -> 32
    // data f64 -> 56
    println!("size of Data: {}", std::mem::size_of::<Data>());
}
```

Comment: The name [`align_of(_val)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.align_of.html) isn't obvious enough?

Answer (score 1):

In order to check (during compilation, not even at run-time), near the definition of your struct `Data` you could add something like

```rust
const _ACTUAL_DATA_ALIGN: usize = std::mem::align_of::<Data>();
const _EXPECTED_DATA_ALIGN: usize = 8 * std::mem::size_of::<Float>();
const _DATA_ALIGN_CHECK: () = assert!(
    _ACTUAL_DATA_ALIGN % _EXPECTED_DATA_ALIGN == 0,
    "Alignment mismatch for struct Data"
);
```

For a conditional compilation, you could add this to your `Cargo.toml`

```ini
[features]
use_f64 = []
```

and then adapt your code like this

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "use_f64")]
pub type Float = f64;

#[cfg(not(feature = "use_f64"))]
pub type Float = f32;

#[cfg_attr(feature = "use_f64", repr(align(64)))]
#[cfg_attr(not(feature = "use_f64"), repr(align(32)))]
struct Data {
    _value: [Float; 6],
    _offset: u32,
    _num: u16,
    _axis: u8,
}

const _ACTUAL_DATA_ALIGN: usize = std::mem::align_of::<Data>();
const _EXPECTED_DATA_ALIGN: usize = 8 * std::mem::size_of::<Float>();
const _DATA_ALIGN_CHECK: () = assert!(
    _ACTUAL_DATA_ALIGN % _EXPECTED_DATA_ALIGN == 0,
    "Alignment mismatch for struct Data"
);

fn main() {
    println!("align of Data: {}", std::mem::align_of::<Data>());
    println!("size of Data: {}", std::mem::size_of::<Data>());
}
/*
$ cargo run
align of Data: 32
size of Data: 32
$ cargo run --features use_f64
align of Data: 64
size of Data: 64
*/
```

Comment: Is it possible to replace `const _EXPECTED_DATA_ALIGN: usize = 8 * std::mem::size_of::<Float>();` with something like `const _EXPECTED_DATA_ALIGN: usize = get_actual_size_of::<Data>();`?

Comment: @Rahn The actual size of `Data` is `std::mem::size_of::<Data>()`, but I don't see how this could help checking the alignment...